# Change the Locale of MKReverseGeocoder's response?

Tags: iphone

I noticed that MKReverseGeocoder returns the country / city / etc. names in the locale of the iPhone's currentLocale. Is there a way to set the currentLocale, or to set the NSLocale instance that a reverseGeocoder is using?

Answer (score -1):

Yes there is, I had the same problem and used this code to great effect:
("en" is for english for example.)

```
[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] setObject: [NSArray arrayWithObjects:@"en", nil] forKey:@"AppleLanguages"];
```

You may or may not synchronize at some point or straight after:

```
[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] synchronize];
```

Now there are a couple of notes on this:

- This will work if for example you are in London and have set your iPhone in another language, it will always return geo names in English.
- What I haven't tested yet but I've seen some odd behaviour is that if have set english as you language but you are abroad (IE Denmark, I was once on a trip to DK) and noticed the revgeocoding was in danish, *but this was before I've used that magic line of code*. Still with my iPhone in english in Denmark I was expecting english results but no cigar at that time.

Comment: -1. This changes the locale for the entire app. Even if you change it back you're still at risk for a concurrency bug.